# CSS Fixed & Fluid li together

Tags: css

I have three images in my separator and I want to make the middle part fluid and left and right portions needs to be fixed. When I open it up like this on the page it needs to look like this;
http://s8.postimg.org/r9dg5v6et/dsadsa.jpg

```
<ul class="separator">
    <li class="sep-orj sep-left"></li>
    <li class="sep-orj sep-middle"></li>
    <li class="sep-orj sep-right"></li>
</ul>

ul.separator {
    width:100%;
}
ul.separator li.sep-orj {
    height:21px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
ul.separator li.sep-left {
    width:3%;
    background: url(............./left-arrow.gif) repeat-x;
}
ul.separator li.sep-middle {
    width:94%;
    background: url(............./middle.gif) repeat-x;
}
ul.separator li.sep-right {
    width:3%;
    background: url(............./right-arrow.gif) repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: change `width:3%;` to `width:30px; //or any value`
But to only `ul.separator li.sep-left` and `ul.separator li.sep-right`

Comment: doesnt work. then I have to make middle portion wheter 92 or 94 percent.. it varies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method using CSS3.

```
ul.separator {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.separator li.sep-orj {
    height:21px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
ul.separator li.sep-left {
    width:15px;
    background: #ccc;
}
ul.separator li.sep-middle {
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 32px); /* 100% minus the left-column, right-column, and border widths */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
ul.separator li.sep-right {
    width:15px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tEwx6/

Don't forget, you will need to use other vendor prefixes for your widths as well. Here is a chart letting you know which browsers support calc: http://caniuse.com/calc

Answer (score 1):

I know there's probably a good reason for using a list for this in your use-case, but just in case, here's a very simple solution using a single `<hr class="separator">` element in the HTML and this chunk of CSS, with only a single wide image:

```
.separator {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    max-width: 1000px; /* ~ width of the image */
    background: url('/img/dsadsa.jpg') left center no-repeat;
}

.separator:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url('/img/dsadsa.jpg') right center no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```